# What is wrong with this code? Code is successfully debugged. But it doesn't shows any output. And also not showing any error message

Tags: python-3.x

My code is based on the Web Scraping concept in Python. My code is running. It doesn't show any error even though it is not displaying any output statement. I am having another 2 files, it just contains about locator. I think those files are not needed. So I didn't paste here. Could you help me?

```
part-1
import requests
from books_pages.whole_page import Allbooks
page_content=requests.get('Some website name').content
page=Allbooks(page_content)
everybooks=page.books
for book in everybooks:
    print(book)

 part-2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from locator_books.whole_pages import List_allbooks_locator
from parser_book.Parsing_book_detail import Individual_book_detail
class Allbooks():
    def __init__(self,page_content):
        self.soup=BeautifulSoup(page_content,'html.parser')
    @property
    def books(self):

        location=List_allbooks_locator.ALLBOOKS
        books=self.soup.select(location)
        return [Individual_book_detail(book) for book in books]


 part-3
import re
from locator_books.indivdual_book import Book_locator
class Individual_book_detail():
    RATING={
        'One':1,
        'Two':2,
        'Three':3,
        'Four':4,
        'Five':5
    }
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent=parent
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Book {self.Name} {self.Price}, {self.Rating} stars>'
    @property
    def Name(self):
        locator=Book_locator.NAME
        title=self.parent.select_one(locator)
        title_tag=title.attrs['title']
        return title_tag
    @property
    def Link(self):
        locator=Book_locator.LINK
        link=self.parent.select_one(locator)
        link_tag=link.attrs['href']
        return link_tag
    @property
    def Price(self):
        locator=Book_locator.PRICE
        price=self.parent.select_one(locator).string
        #price_tag=price.attrs['class']
        expression='£([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)'
        evaluate=re.search(price,expression)
        return float(evaluate.group(1))
    @property
    def Rating(self):
        locator=Book_locator.RATING
        rating=self.parent.select_one(locator)
        rating_tag=rating.attrs['class']
        rating=[r for r in rating_tag if r != 'star-rating' ]
        #rating1=filter(lambda x:  x!='star-rating',rating_tag)
        return Individual_book_detail.RATING.get(rating[0])


I am expecting book details from the website. But its showing
Process finished with exit code 0
```